# What is this tree and fruits?

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

Please help me identify this tree and its fruits that have sweet taste and very small soft seeds:

[image]
[image]

It grows in the Mediterranean region.

Comment: [*Ficus sycomorus*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_sycomorus) possibly...it's a type of fig (*Ficus*)

Comment: @user33690 Why don't you turn your comment to a proper answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a **sycamore fig** (*Ficus sycomorus*)- a type of Mediterranean fig.

[image]

[image]

[For details: see this wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_sycomorus)